# Can you repeatedly deploy an APK with 'adb install' without uninstalling first?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Since I'm really not a fan of Eclipse I'm developing my Android app by following the rules listed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html

When I'm deploying with the 'adb install' command I have to manually uninstall the APK from the emulator every time or else the install won't work.  Is there any way to bypass this?  It's fairly annoying having to add this step in every time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, use the `adb install -r` switch.

Running `adb` with no options will give help.

Comment: And you can also do "adb uninstall com.yourpackagename"; it's manual, but it's pretty fast.  (The -r option is the answer to your question, this is just FYI)